# Angular 2 - custom validators issues

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to create a simple custom validator. basically if one variable (behalf) is true, the field must be mandatory. That's all.

I don't know why, but I cannot read the variable behalf. It's throw undefined. Any clue about how to handle this ?

```
behalf = false;
private validateName(){
    if (this.behalf && this.nameB.text != '') {
        return {
            invalidName : true
        };
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}    
constructor (private builder: FormBuilder){
    this.title = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.name = new Control('', this.validateName);
    this.type = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.desc = new Control('');
    this.hideTitle = new Control('');
    this.end = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.formBook = builder.group({
        title: this.title,
        name: this.name,
        type: this.type,
        desc: this.desc,
        hideTitle: this.hideTitle,
        end: this.end
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you reference a function so the `this` doesn't correspond to the component object when this function is called.

You could try the following to force the execution of the function in the context of the component instance:

```
this.name = new Control('', (control) => {
  this.validateName(control);
});
```

or using the `bind` method:

```
this.name = new Control('', this.validateName.bind(this));
```

Be careful when using the `bind` method in TypeScript:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think This method is Useful To You.

```
addCustomerForm :any;
constructor (private builder: FormBuilder){

this.customername = new Control("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
ValidationService.alphaValidator]));

this.addCustomerForm = formBuilder.group({
     customername: this.customername,
 });

 this.customerName = '';
```